# Generating ICS Timezone info out of pytz zoneinfo

Tags: python, icalendar

I am trying to generate proper ICS (calendar invites) time zone portions out of time zone names. Typical information includes offsets w.r.t. UTC and the start and end dates of daylight savings time.

Apparently, this info is present in pytz zoneinfo files. However, I'm not clear on how to extract it from there. It could be hard-coded there, so that instead of listing the general pattern of the 3rd Sunday in October, it would simply list a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the dates of switching between standard time and daylight savings time are hard-coded. So, I ended up extracting them and, for a given date, finding a pair of dates before and after that date.